# Filtering process value (PV) or controller output (CO)?

Tags: pid-controller

In the case of a noisy process value, what are the pros and cons of filtering the process value (PV) versus filtering the controller output (CO) or maybe both?

Filtering PV changes the process model and affects PID constants. I was told that ISA standard recommend not filtering the process value in a PID but I didn't find proof of it. By filtering PV you already have all in (constants for a given first order filter applied).

Thanks

Comment: "I'm told that..."  If possible, check for yourself.  If you can get your hands on that standard, you should read it.

Comment: @TimWescott sorry, unfortunately I don't have access to it, would love to have an advice on the above mentioned question 

Comment: If you have a university library close by that has the standard, you may be able to visit.  If you're a university graduate, and your university extends library privileges to alumni, you can check with them.  As I said in my answer -- I can't see why they're saying that, unless they're pushing you away from plastering over a measurement problem that really should just be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, fixing up your process value measurement is always better, assuming that it's a noisy measurement and that the value itself isn't bouncing around.

If the PID controller is a linear device, then -- aside from what the controller "thinks" is happening -- there's absolutely no difference between filtering the input or filtering the output.  That's because if you have two perfectly linear systems (i.e., your filter and your controller), the order of filtering doesn't matter.

If your PID controller has no monitoring*, then the only difference between filtering the input and filtering the output is how it affects the controller nonlinearities.

I'm trying to think of cases, and in all of them it's seeming to me like filtering the process value is better.  You'll be less likely to hit limits within the controller for both the proportional and differential actions, and there's some styles of integrator anti-windup that could be "pumped" by excessive noise, partially or entirely disabling your integrator action.

* I'm not going to comment on monitoring beyond this, because I don't know what's done in industry.

Comment: It could be that what the ISA is saying is "don't fix poor process measurements by low-pass filtering your PID input (or output)".  But without reading the source material, I can't say.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather filter in the forward path, i.e. the output. Here's why:

Consider a loop with forward gain A (includes transfer functions of both plant and controller) and feedback gain B (often 1).

CL gain is A/(1+AB)

We are deciding where to add LPF = 1/(1 + s/p). We can put it into A or into B.

The denominator of the CL expression, hence the stability criterion, is the same either way.  But if you work out the algebra, adding the LPF to B introduces a CL zero that is not there if we add the same LPF to A instead. All things being equal, CL zero in the loop's bandwidth = step response overshoot.

If the LPF is beyond the loop bandwidth, less of an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the method you use to calculate your PID tuning parameters (I used lambda tuning) these methods sometimes already accounting for a degree of process model mismatch from your specified tuning parameters this is not the same as filtering but it does help smooth erratic "non-ideal behavior of a process".

Let me give an example for a first order process with a process gain (Kp) of 2 and a tau of 10 seconds, using a controller gain (Kc) of Kc = Tau/Kp in theory gives you the lowest IAE PID which is desired.  But no one uses this in the practice because there is always some degree of model mismatch to the tuning parameters!  We can usually compensate for this mismatch better by adjusting our tuning parameters than by over-filtering.  In the example above include the term lambda (an integer) in the formula and Kc = Tau/(Kp*Lambda).  The greater the lambda the less model mismatch and white noise will cause the PID OP to ring/oscillate.  But there are several things you should be aware of such as units and what model your process is 1st order, second order, integrating.  These actually all affect the way Kc is calculated!

But the rule for filtering PV is that Tf < 1/3 of process tau where Tf is (Filter time for a first order filter).  If the filter time constant becomes too large the dynamics of the filter begin to become significant/dominate the response of the PID.  If you had a Tf of 30s on the example problem above the OP of the PID would just constantly oscillate!

I do not filter the OP of the PID because if you calculated your tuning parameters using well established tuning methods you should be accounting for the model mismatch this way and filtering the white noise on the front end of the PID using the rule Tf<1/3 tau (first order process).